# Building iOS App Clip using Flutter without going over 10MB limit?

Tags: flutter, apple-appclips

I'm doing a little bit of research into App Clip (and then Instant Apps) using Flutter.

Here are my findings:

- I successfully build and run sample app [ios_app_clip](https://github.com/flutter/samples/tree/master/ios_app_clip)
- I successfully build and run "my own" application with App Clip by following the [Adding an iOS App Clip target](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/platform-integration/ios-app-clip) tutorial
- In both cases application run successfully in simulator/device, but is then rejected by Apple when uploaded because App Clip is to big (little over 10Mb)
- I build variant without using material (and manage to put app down to ~8Mb) but Apple still complains that app is to big

Here are my questions:

- if I understand correctly (by reading on the internet), size of the Flutter app (and subsequently App Clip) is big because "material" lib in included - which is logical because lib must be included if you want to draw anything (also in App Clip)
- I build a version of application where I didn't include any of the parent app components and the application was still rejected - does this means that "material" lib is included in any case?
- Is there I way to NOT include any of the Flutter libs in App Clip and develop App Clip using xCode and native code (I know this is stupid)?
- Did anybody manage to create an App Clip and push it to the AppStoreConnect?

Thank you for any answers!

Answer (score -1):

You don't have to follow the steps of `Adding an iOS App Clip target` tutorial.

You can simple add project target of `App Clip`, and add swift code for your Clip part. No need to import anything from flutter project.

Comment: I understand this but this means that application will not have the same UI

Comment: you can always create same UI by flutter & swift/objc if you follow the same design. by the way,  Clips should be small part of your app,